# How to make Wildfly 14 not overwrite a symlinked standalone.xml?

Tags: windows-7, wildfly, symlink

My `standalone.xml` resides in the repo for inclusion in the docker image. As I have no working docker on my local Windows 7 machine, I'm using a local Wildfly 14 (14.0.1.Final). I tried starting Wildfly with the `jboss.server.config.dir` property pointing to this standalone, but then Wildfly complains about not finding `logging.properties` in the same directory, so I must have my `standalone.xml` in the Wildfly config directory.

To avoid having a possibly outdated copy of `standalone.xml` in `wildfly-14.0.1.Final\standalone\configuration`, I created a symlink:

```
>mklink standalone-myapp.xml c:\path\to\standalone.xml
>dir standalone-myapp.xml
...
07.11.2018  10:24    <SYMLINK>      standalone-myapp.xml [c:\path\to\standalone.xml]
```

However when Wildfly starts, it overwrites the symlinked file and it's not any longer a symlink:

```
>dir standalone-myapp.xml
...
07.11.2018  10:28            23'069 standalone-myapp.xml
```

Can this behaviour somehow be configured or fixed?

#### Update

In fact using the read-only mode (`--read-only-server-config`) allows to specify a `standalone.xml` in a directory without `logging.properties`. If I had know this option I wouldn't have experimented with a symlink.

I still think it's a bug that Wildfly doesn't update the file pointed at by the symlink, but it doesn't bother me anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pull your standalone configuration from git ;) or start WildFly in read-only mode thus avoiding this overwriting (but loosing any changes you might be doing on the configuration).

Comment: The read-only mode (`--read-only-server-config=standalone-myapp.xml`) is exactly what I wanted. Thanks